# Xamarin forms - Animate ListView viewcell Item (border or background) every 5 seconds

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know how to animate a ListView item periodically?
I am trying to animate an item every 5 seconds to catch a user attention in a Listview based on an observablecollection property.
Is the Device.StartTimer the way to tackle it and loop through all the listview items?
The animation duration should not surpass 2 seconds by increasing the border width or fading the background color of the listview item.

Can someone help or point me to the right direction please?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/

Comment: get the reference of the desired "Adapter", in this case, the row, and animate it using `View.Animate` extension provided by XF

Comment: ever figured that out?